# Correct use of "consist"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

Which one of the following two sentences is correct?

> 1. We are only concerned with crystal systems which *consist of* an inversion center.
> 2. We are only concerned with crystal systems which *consist* an inversion center.

I really can't tell the difference. If they are both grammatically correct, which usage is more formal? (I hope I am not being too vague).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The verb *consist* is never used without a preposition and it usually takes either *of* or *in*. In your example, it should be *consist of*. Thus, the first sentence is correct while the second is wrong. From the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1235486#m_en_us1235486):

> 1 (**consist of**) be composed or made up of
>
> - (**consist in**) have as an essential feature
>
> 2  (**consist with**) *archaic* be consistent with

I should also add that it is probably not uncommon for some speakers to drop the *of* in conversation, but this should by all means be avoided in written contexts.

Comment: @Jimi-- What do you think of kiamlaluno's suggestion of using "consisting of" ? I am not trying to start a rivalry here by asking your comments on other answers. I would like to understand the reasoning behind it and hope to learn from these discussions.

Comment: @Srikanth: It's a good suggestion, and just another to rephrase your sentence. Personally, I would prefer *which consist of* in this case. *Consisting of* sounds awkward sometimes. I think I use it much, much less often than *consists of*. To make it better, I might say: "...crystal systems consisting of inversion centers". Seems *consisting of* goes better with plural components!

Comment: @Srikanth: On a completely different angle, you just might want to do away with *consists of* and use something else because *consists* usually deals with multiple components. Here, you only have an *inversion center*. Thus, you might say: "...systems which/that have an inversion center", "...systems with an inversion center", etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Consist of* means "be composed or made up of".
The NOAD reports three different meanings of *consist*, but the verb is always used with a preposition: *consist of*, *consist in*, *consist with*.

> The exhibition consists of 180 drawings.
>   His duties consist in taking the condition of the barometer.
>   The information perfectly consists with our friend's account.

If I understood what you mean, I would write the sentence as:

> We are only concerned with crystal systems **consisting of** an inversion center.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a feeling you are right. All I can say is that it sounds better to use "consisting of". What made you suggest using "consisting of" instead of "consist of" ?

Comment: @Srikanth: Participial phrases function as adjectives. Take as example "she was annoyed by the crumpled newspapers lying on the kitchen floor"; "lying on the kitchen floor" describes _newspapers_.