# Water comprises/composes/combines/consists two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom

Tags: word-choice, verbs, transitive-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use what word to express that something consists of something else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/when-do-you-use-what-word-to-express-that-something-consists-of-something-else)
>   [Does a whole “compose” its parts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/does-a-whole-compose-its-parts)
>   [Correct use of “consist”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15853/correct-use-of-consist)

> Water *comprises/composes/combines/consists* two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.

Can anyone let me know the correct usage in this sentence?

Comment: Note that it is two hydrogen *atoms* and one oxygen *atom* that make one water *molecule*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible correct usages.

You can say "Water *comprises* two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule".

You can say "Water *consists of* two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule".

You can say "Water *is composed of* two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule".

You can probably say "Water *is a combination of* two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule", though it sounds a bit off to me.

Note that they all have different structure, and subtly different semantics.

Comment: “Water is a combination of two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule” isn't “off”, merely verbose.  One can also grammatically say “Water combines two hydrogen molecules and one oxygen molecule”, which does sound a bit off.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's just the verbosity that felt a bit strange to me. Maybe because "combination" is too vague a word. Dunno.

Comment: I agree with your grammar, but (as @neil states) the science would dictate: *A water molecule comprises two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom. A water molecule consists of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom. A water molecule is composed of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.*

Comment: I want best answer out of these.

Comment: There's no best answer out of these. I'm fond of "comprises", personally, but that's a personal stylistic choice, not a "wrong" or "right". Note @neil and JLG's clarifications that you're talking about water *molecules*, not water in general, and choose the one that sounds nicest to you.

Comment: -1  sorry, but each of those statements is wrong

Comment: Care to elaborate on *why* they're wrong, @wim?

Comment: Because, whilst water may be made up of hydrogen and oxygen, by no stretch of the imagination is it made up of hydrogen and oxygen [molecules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule).  That's just not how it works.  A hydrogen molecule is H2, and an Oxygen molecule is O2, you can mix a bag of each of those together and you'll simply get a bag of mixed up gases (you won't get any water without inducing combustion somehow)

Comment: First of all, you're not actually responding to the OP's question, which is a linguistic question, not a chemical one. 
Secondly, no one said anything about the process to create the water molecule, just its composition. Before editing, the OP did erroneously use "hydrogen molecule" and "oxygen molecule", but since this was fixed via an edit more than 6 hours before your comment (and downvote), I really don't see what you're responding to.

Answer (score 4):

The last time I had water, there were a lot more than two hydrogen atoms involved, and very many oxygen atoms.  For this to make sense, you have to make it clear that you're talking about a single molecule of water, not water in general.

My preference for how to express this is the following.

> A molecule of water consists of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity use *composed of*, perhaps.  *Comprise* can be seen in two opposite senses--whether the whole comprises its parts, or the parts comprise the whole.

OED under 4b:

> The house comprises box-room, nine bed-rooms, bath-room, etc.

but under 8b:

> These essays together with those contained in this volume comprise the total of C. S. Lewis's essays on literature.